# Change a label text with the forms name in a string eg. String1.label1.text

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am trying to create a Function that does everything automatically. Here is my current code:

```
Public Sub IncrementValueBeta(SlideDescription As String, SlideNumber As Integer, FormName As String)
    ChangeSlide (SlideNumber)
    MsgBox ("Test: " + SlideDescription)
    AddClicks = FormName.ClickedTimes.Text + 1
    FormName.ClickedTimes.Text = AddClicks
End Sub
```

This will add a number to the value but I am trying to make the code more concise without having to do `if FormName = "Slide1"` a 1000 times as it is a huge questionnaire.

The user will type `"FormName"` e.g., `"Form1"`. In the code, it will use it like `FormName.ClickedTimes.Caption = AddClicks` so in the slide if the slide was 25 clicks it would be 26 that's already working but only if I do  `Slide3` not `FormName` is there a way I can do this? If you know how, can you help me because it will be a real pain if I have to do `If bah = "bah" then` `elseif bah = "bah" then` 1000 times.

This will basically Change the text of the Form label, to Eg, the user has clicked yes i like sports, the code will load the module/class and change label1.text to +1 clicks and it will change label2.text to "Question 2" but it doesn't know what form it is so it will use the text in FormName that was given with the arguments to find out what form it is editing. thats what im trying to accomplish here

In short, i just want it to find the form from FormName and View `FormName.Label1.text = ""` as `Form1.Label1.text = ""`

Comment: Can you post more code? I am not sure what is not working here...

Comment: it doesnt see FormName as an Class/Form to call/Edit eg it see's it as Text.Item not Class.Item, i want it to recognize it as a Class/Form

Comment: You cant because FormName is a string, unless you create a new class. Or an Extension method, depending on your need.

Comment: If you can help me, please help me. all it needs to do is see A String as a class. if anyone can help me do that it would be awesome!

Comment: So you want to access different slides by 1. String input, and by 2. user Increment?

Comment: Yes, so String "FormName" is the Slide and Integer "SlideNumber" is the number of the slide and "SlideDesc" is a tiny bit of info that will be displayed. So with this FormName.Label1.Text = "", so in everyslide if its been clicked it will open the slide and +1 to the label1.text wich will be 0 and increment over the clicks placed! @Arman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Assuming there is only one instance of the desired Form, try something like this:

```
Public Sub IncrementValueBeta(SlideDescription As String, SlideNumber As Integer, FormName As String)
    ChangeSlide(SlideNumber)

    Dim frmTarget As Form = Nothing
    For Each frm As Form In Application.OpenForms
        If frm.Name.ToUpper = FormName.ToUpper Then
            frmTarget = frm
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If Not IsNothing(frmTarget) Then
        Dim matches() As Control = frmTarget.Controls.Find("ClickedTimes", True)
        If matches.Length > 0 Then
            AddClicks = matches(0).Text + 1
            matches(0).Text = AddClicks
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I would also go with the way of using dictionaries.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private slides As New Dictionary(Of Integer, String)

    Private currentSlideNumber As Integer
    Private currentSlideDescription As String

    Public Sub IncrementByClick()
        currentSlideDescription = slides(currentSlideNumber + 1)
        currentSlideNumber += 1

        ChangeSlide(currentSlideDescription)
    End Sub

    Public Sub ChangeSlide(ByVal slideDescription As String)
        currentSlideNumber = SelectSlideNumberByDesc(slideDescription)
        currentSlideDescription = slides(currentSlideNumber)
        MessageBox.Show("Successfully changed the slide to slide no. " & currentSlideNumber)
    End Sub

    Private Function SelectSlideNumberByDesc(ByVal slideDesc As String)
        Dim slideNumber As Integer
        For Each slide In slides
            If slide.Value = slideDesc Then
                slideNumber = slide.Key
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        Return slideNumber
    End Function

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        slides.Add(1, "SLIDE_ONE")
        slides.Add(2, "SLIDE_TWO")
        slides.Add(3, "SLIDE_THREE")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ChangeSlide(TextBox1.Text)
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnNext_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click
        IncrementByClick()
    End Sub
End Class
```

With by clicking button1, the slide will change according to the slide description the user have entered in the textbox.

By clicking btnNext, next slide will load accordingly.

OO way is way better but this should be enough to show it.